# WHILE loop doesnt ends in UPDATE command TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one TSQL command that I use in SSIS sequence container in Execute sql task executable.
I need to insert data into archive DB/table that is same as PROD and attached on same instance of SQL 2016 standard edt.
I insert about 5671294 records and in the mean time update the flag in other help/stage table that use in further checks.
My Loop never ends after updating last 71294 records. On Activity monitor i can see stuck in UPDATE command and no columns for updating.
Another problem is that this works very slow (DB in simple recovery).

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT  ArchiveDB..Table ON
GO

DECLARE @InsertRowCnt INT
SET @InsertRowCnt = 1

DECLARE @InsertBatchSize INT
SET @InsertBatchSize=100000

WHILE (@InsertRowCnt > 0)

BEGIN 

DECLARE @OutputTbl AS TABLE(BSGID INT)

INSERT INTO ArchiveDB..Table ([BSGID], [Identifier],[SystemCombinationItems], [TotalItems], [TotalBankers],[SpecialCombinationID], [ModifiedOn], [ModifiedBy], [CreatedOn])
OUTPUT inserted.BSGID INTO @OutputTbl(BSGID)  
SELECT TOP (@InsertBatchSize) s.BSGID, s.Identifier,  
 s.SystemCombinationItems, s.TotalItems, s.TotalBankers, s.SpecialCombinationID, s.ModifiedOn, 
 s.ModifiedBy, s.CreatedOn
FROM ProdDB.dbo.Table AS s WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
 ArchiveDB.dbo.StageTable AS t WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.BSGID = t.BSGID
WHERE t.IsInserted IS NULL


----Updating stage table contains 2 columns BSGID int,IsInserted int null

UPDATE arh
SET arh.IsInserted=1
FROM ArchiveDB.dbo.StageTable AS arh WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN @OutputTbl AS a  
ON arh.BSGID=a.BSGID
WHERE arh.IsInserted is null

SET @InsertRowCnt = @@ROWCOUNT;

END

SET IDENTITY_INSERT  ArchiveDB..Table OFF
GO
```

Comment: Aside: You declare `@OutputTbl` inside the `while` loop, but TSQL doesn't limit the scope of the declaration to the loop. If you `select Count( @OutputTbl );` inside the loop you'll find that it keeps growing each time through the loop. You should move the declaration out of the loop and `delete` all of the rows inside the loop after the `update` and capturing `@@RowCount`.

Comment: This works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT  ArchiveDB..Table ON
GO

DECLARE @InsertRowCnt INT
--------------------------------
SELECT @InsertRowCnt=COUNT(*)
FROM ProdDB.dbo.Table AS s WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
 ArchiveDB.dbo.StageTable AS t WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.BSGID = t.BSGID
WHERE t.IsInserted IS NULL
----------------------------

DECLARE @InsertBatchSize INT
SET @InsertBatchSize=100000

WHILE (@InsertRowCnt > 0)

BEGIN 

DECLARE @OutputTbl AS TABLE(BSGID INT)

INSERT INTO ArchiveDB..Table ([BSGID], [Identifier],[SystemCombinationItems], 
[TotalItems], [TotalBankers],[SpecialCombinationID], [ModifiedOn], [ModifiedBy], 
[CreatedOn])
OUTPUT inserted.BSGID INTO @OutputTbl(BSGID)  
SELECT TOP (@InsertBatchSize) s.BSGID, s.Identifier,  
 s.SystemCombinationItems, s.TotalItems, s.TotalBankers, s.SpecialCombinationID, 
s.ModifiedOn, 
s.ModifiedBy, s.CreatedOn
FROM ProdDB.dbo.Table AS s WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
ArchiveDB.dbo.StageTable AS t WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.BSGID = t.BSGID
WHERE t.IsInserted IS NULL


----Updating stage table contains 2 columns BSGID int,IsInserted int null

UPDATE arh
SET arh.IsInserted=1
FROM ArchiveDB.dbo.StageTable AS arh WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN @OutputTbl AS a  
ON arh.BSGID=a.BSGID
WHERE arh.IsInserted is null
--------------------------------
SELECT @InsertRowCnt=COUNT(*)
FROM ProdDB.dbo.Table AS s WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
ArchiveDB.dbo.StageTable AS t WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.BSGID = t.BSGID
WHERE t.IsInserted IS NULL
----------------------------

END

SET IDENTITY_INSERT  ArchiveDB..Table OFF
GO
```

Comment: Please add some text explaining your answer.